# How to make SWT Browser control use Mozilla/Firefox instead of WebKit on Linux(Ubuntu 14)

Tags: java, linux, swt, ubuntu-14.04, xulrunner

I want to make SWT 4.4.2 browser to use Mozilla on Linux (Ubuntu 14.o4 LTS) whenever I run my application SWT uses webkit. Any idea how to make SWT to use Mozilla?

As an example I am using following code of SWT to open the embedded browser.
Linux Ubuntu version

```java
public class DisplayMozillaVersion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Device.DEBUG = true;
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        System.out.println(">>>Snippet creating SWT.MOZILLA-style Browser");
        try {
            new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
            System.out.println(">>>succeeded");
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println(">>>This failed with the following error:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n\nSnippet creating SWT.NONE-style Browser");
            try {
                new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
                System.out.println(">>>succeeded");
            } catch (Error e2) {
                System.out.println(">>>This failed too, with the following error:");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

The above code always failed for the Mozilla (`SWT.MOZILLA`) and gives following errors

```
No more handles [Browser style SWT.MOZILLA and Java system property org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla are not supported with GTK 3 as XULRunner is not ported for GTK 3 yet]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.MozillaDelegate.(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.(Unknown Source)
    at swtbrowserapp.SWTBrowserApp.(SWTBrowserApp.java:72)
    at swtbrowserapp.SWTBrowserApp.main(SWTBrowserApp.java:38)
```

When I use `SWT.NONE` it always uses WebKit. What is the way to run the Mozilla as SWT browser on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Doesn't the error code say it all? Apparently there is no XULRunner port for gtk3 yet. You could try forcing your application to use gtk2 instead.

Comment: How can I force my SWT app to use gtk2 instead? Anything else I need to change on ubuntu?

Comment: You'll need to set an environment variable before starting your application. There's more information [here](https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/how-to-tell-if-you-are-running-eclipse-on-gtk2-or-on-gtk3/) and [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/R4_4/new_and_noteworthy.html).

Comment: I am using SWT.jar file in NETbeans IDE does the link you mentioned applied to Netbeans as well?

Comment: The example uses eclipse, but it will work for your application as well. Just set the environment variable before you run your code.

Comment: How can I set the environment variable. Can u give the code snipped that can fit in the above example code?

Comment: After setting the environment variable on ubuntu 14.04 export SWT_GTK3=0. The error code is changed now and it is giving following error <blink>Could not instantiate Browser: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at swtbrowserapp.SWTBrowserApp.<init>(SWTBrowserApp.java:81)
 at swtbrowserapp.SWTBrowserApp.main(SWTBrowserApp.java:39)
</blink>

Comment: Looks like you haven't set the required environment variable for XULRunner. [Here](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux) is some information.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 4.4.2 Swt Browser works with Xulrunner 10 and 24 (xulrunner is the underlying rendering engine for mozilla firefox) . You need to download this from [xulrunner download](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/)

Eclipse 4.4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 by default runs in gtk2(this is changed in 4.5 and above). So no change required there.

you can add the following switches to eclipse.ini at the end

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=<path to xulrunner libs>
```

This should set the eclipse to use xulrunner rendering engine

Comment: I am not using Eclipse IDE. I am uisng SWT 4.4.2 in  NET beans IDE. Please suggest how it automatically picks the mozilla firefox when run it on  ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You can use java.lang.system.setProperty to set the property org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath and pass SWT.Mozilla when you create Browser.

Comment: @user2724058 Did you ever find a way around this problem? a lot of people of give instances of using eclipse, but I have a similar situation with you using SWT in NET beans IDE and exporting the app as a standalone with the SWT Jars embedded in the app and XULRunner installed on the target system, from what I am realizing it seems to be a SWT versioning problem, you think? I have a different architecture though and my app points to the XULRunner path as described above.